# Safe FreeBSD test on system running debian with zpools

Tags: debian, freebsd, zfs

So I bought a nice cheap used server in order to turn it into a file server + VM Host, every thing was neat in the prototype VM.

But reality comes in, motherboard power control over fans is pretty buggy (while idling at 30°C, fans gets to max than slow down slowly and once reach the lowest get back to max annoyance and so on).
Seeing that I wasn't able to read fan speed from sysctl, and seeing most forums quite pessimistic, I pretty much panicked (this server is in my garage and need to be moderately noisy, not the 7k rpm x 3 kind of noise)
So I put it under debian jessie, got fan control to work, get my linux... zfs pool and probably should be happy as a pig.

The fact is I'm not, I still want to get back to freebsd for a few reasons.

I though of booting on a live version of freebsd or true os but the freebsd one seems more of a rescue tool box, and the true os one does't exist.

I need a system where I will have time to test a few port, and maybe a few kernel option **without endangering the existing zpool**.

I though installing it on an other drive while testing and avoiding any zfs import of my pool, or even removing those 6 disk during those test.

Any suggestion or idea concerning the test plateforme, the migration?

Comment: This blog sort of does what you want to do: https://ericmccorkleblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/cohabiting-freebsd-and-gentoo-linux-on-a-common-zfs-volume/  except that it does FreeBSD first, then Gentoo. I've not read thoroughly, but head about it on a podcast some months ago.